# How get indexPath and write in NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm starter!
I have 7 cell-(7 days) in TableViewController 
How get indexPath for all selected cells and write in NSMutableArray
My Project is Alarm Clock

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

}
```

please help or tell me something

Comment: look into indexPathsForSelectedRows method!

Comment: Thanks -  Teja Nandamuri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get indexpath array using  this.

NSArray *indexPathArray = [yourTableView indexPathsForSelectedRows];